# Old low quality question with correct guess as comment

Tags: discussion

I was looking through old unanswered Android questions, to either answer them or vote to close where there is reason to. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816436/cant-get-startactivity-to-work) which is clearly low quality and doesn't have enough information to actually answer...  Except that it has an 'answer' in the form of a comment.

A high rep user correctly guessed what the issue might be, causing the author to state that it solved their problem and then presumably never return to their question again.

What's the correct thing to do with a situation like this? Flag to close anyway?  Edit the question? Transcribe the comment to an actual answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Flag to close anyway?

Yes.  If a question is woefully incomplete and is, as a result, unanswerable, you vote to close it.  That's what closures are for.  It's certainly less important for such an old question, but it's certainly not *wrong*.

> Edit the question?

Do you really think that you could edit the question into a good question?  If so, yes, feel free.  If it'd still be a crap question after you did your best to fix it, then don't bother polishing a turd and move on to a question that could actually benefit from that level of effort.

> Transcribe the comment to an actual answer?

Given that you've asserted the question is fundamentally unanswerable in its current state, no.  If the question were actually a good, answerable, question, that happened to be answered in comments, then sure.

Comment: +1 The only caveat I have to add to this is if it were a popular question pulling in decent amount of views, it would be worthwhile editing for clarification and posting the answer proper. (Of course this isn't the case in the given example)

Comment: @Robotnik That assumes that the question is inherently salvageable.  When there simply isn't enough information in the question to determine what it's asking, there's no way for anyone but the author to fix that with edits.

Comment: That's just how I tend to look at questions: as being salvagable in some way, especially if the question had a decent answer and was generally popular (neither of these being the case on this question).